# How to setup SQL data once per Spec and clear it after Spec is completed?

Tags: spring, groovy, transactions, spock

I want to prepare `SQL` data **once per Spec** and remove it after Spec is completed. It should be done by **Spring service**

As I understand I can do following:

- I can do it in `setup:` but it will lead to too many useless
  inserts/rollbacks (if I've got few data-driven tests)
- I can use `@BeforeTransaction` ([check](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/blob/master/spock-spring/src/test/groovy/org/spockframework/spring/TransactionalGroovySqlExample.groovy) this example) - how to clear data after test is completed?

Comment: What about my answer? Does it fit your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your test method with @Test and @Transactional and it will automatically roll back when the test is complete.

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want to achieve. It will rollback on every test iteration. I need to rollback data only once - after spec is completed

Comment: It is considered best practice to not share data between tests because you could end up relying on the order of execution or a newly introduced test could break another one in the same class. It is more fragile that way and the cost of creating and wiping data for each test is minimal.

Comment: This method interferes with any @Transactional methods you may have, such as in a service, so testing that those roll back correctly will not work properly